# Preciso mesmo ter na tag IMG os atributos src e ng-src? Qual a função de cada?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular

Vi aqui que temos a criação da *tag* `<img>` com os atributos `src` e `ng-src`.

Precisa mesmo ser assim?

Ainda mais que aqui os dois atributos possuem o mesmo valor.

Comment: A diferença entre o `src` e o `ng-src` é que usando a diretiva do Angular é possível atribuir um source à  imagem através de um valor no controller.

Comment: Aqui onde? Pode colocar o exemplo?

Comment: Por que <img class="img" ng-src="{{item.caminho}}"> vira <img class="img" src=".../Imagem.jpg" ng-src=".../Imagem.jpg">? saberia me dizer se este é o comportamento padrão?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-src` é usado pelo AngularJS, `src` não é. O `src` é o que você conhece do HTML, ele carrega uma imagem com aquele nome, pode-se dizer que ele é estático. O `ng-src` é interpretado pelo AngularJS e se a informação que estiver ali for correta ele poderá carregar uma imagem de acordo com o identificador constante ali que será vinculado no momento adequado.

Não se esqueça que o HTML feito para AngularJS é um *template* que deverá ter partes preenchidas no momento da execução com valores que façam sentido.

Este exemplo pegará o valor de `variavel` e usará como nome a ser carregado.

```
<img ng-src="http://www.seudominio.com.br/imagem/{{variavel}}"/>
```

O valor provavelmente será definido no *controller*.

Já o exemplo abaixo carregará uma imagem chamada `{{variavel}}`, que provavelmente não é o que deseja.

```
<img src="http://www.seudominio.com.br/imagem/{{variavel}}"/>
```

Agora se fizer:

```
<img ng-src="http://www.seudominio.com.br/imagem/variavel"/>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Angular.html).

vai carregar uma imagem chamada `variavel`, afinal não está usando o *escape* para indicar que ali vai um código AngularJS e não um HTML puro.

[Documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

Comment: Entendi.
Então Com o ng-qualquer-coisa no angular template podemos alterar o valor dinamicamente após execução angular.

Mas no caso da img eu tenho após execução angular o src e o ng-src. Por que tenho os 2 no html renderizado?

Não era so ára ter o src pois o mesmo foi gerado automaticamente?
Por que o angular deixa lá seu 'lixo'?

Abs

Comment: Basicamente é isso. Não sei porque tem os dois. Você sequer colocou isso na pergunta, não deu um contexto, nada. O AngularJS não vai mexer no que você fez.

Comment: Na pergunta talvez não deixei claro sobre o src e ng-src.

Seguem dados:
Html renderizado:
<img class="img" src=".../Imagem.jpg" ng-src=".../Imagem.jpg">

Template:
<img class="img" ng-src="{{item.caminho}}">

Então depois de renderizado o html ele gera o src.

obrigado pelas respostas.

Comment: só é preciso um deles